# Printing a string object from an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I stored some strings in objects and added the objects to an NSMutableArray.  Now I want to print the strings in each element of the array.  Clearly, I'm doing something wrong.  I'm going to back and review these basics, but I was hoping someone could explain how I can print the string instead of the what looks to be the element address.

```
/** interface **/
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString*myNumber;

-(void)setNumber: (NSString*) randomNumber;


/** implementation **/

@synthesize myNumber;

-(void) setNumber:(NSString *)randomNumber
{
    myNumber = randomNumber;    
} 

/**main**/

Fraction * aFrac = [[Fraction alloc] init];
[aFrac setNumber:@"5/6"];
Fraction * bFrac = [[Fraction alloc] init];
[bFrac setNumber:@"2/3"];

NSMutableArray * myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:aFrac];
[myArray addObject:bFrac];

int i;
for(i = 0; i<2; ++i)
{
    id myArrayElement  = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@", myArrayElement);
}

for(i = 0; i<2; ++i)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", myArray[i]);    
}
```

Both for loops print the same thing.

Comment: What are you expecting? Both for loops do exactly the same thing in two different ways. Are you expecting them to print different things? Also, it would be helpful if you edit your question to show the output you are getting and the output you are *expecting*

Comment: Well once I couldn't get the first for loop to print what I wanted, I tried the second loop.  I was hoping for both to print the same thing..which they did.

Comment: @JasonCoco they aren't really equal jason ;) for NSArray they are typically equal but different methods are called so if a custom array class they _could_ differ (they won't! but they could :D)

Comment: @Daij-Djan yes, but he is not using some other custom class, he's using an `NSArray`, so they are equal here.

Comment: ok, was being picky -- sorry -- ( different methods are called anyways ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the `Fraction` type you created has a NSString property or method named number (to match the `-setNumber:` method), in which case you would use the following code to print it:

`NSLog("%@", [myArrayElement number]);`

Or, for the second loop:

`NSLog("%@", [myArray[i] number]);`

Comment: I wouldn't even expose the decimal number

Comment: @Daij-Djan There is no decimal number exposed on the Fraction class. Additionally, the question specifically asked "how to print a string in an object"

Comment: sorry. i assumed the fraction class made sense. sorry

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a custom object to NSLog you have to override the -(NSString)description method in that object.

So in your Fraction class if you simply override this function like so

```
- (NSString*)description
{
  return self.myNumber;
}
```

that should log out what you want.

I would probably think about renaming that property from number as you are storing a string.

Hope that helps

Comment: You don't ever 'have to' override the `description` method. However the implementation inherited from `NSObject` simply prints the name of the receiver's class followed by the address of the instance, which is the behavior the OP observed in his example. You can always override the inherited method if you want to customize the description it returns, but you never have to do so.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Call me nitpicky, but as written it's slightly misleading, and would be clearer if properly qualified (e.g., as per your comment, *"if you want it to log a different string"*).

Comment: @jlehr :) Me being really nitpicky myself, I respect that and I agree with you! :)

Comment: Since I was able to print what I wanted using `[myArray[i] myNumber]`, is that considered overriding the (NSString) description method?  I thought I'm just calling for the `myNumber` property to print instead of the address.

Answer (score 0):

In your code both for loop meaning has same only, try below

```
 for(i = 0; i<2; ++i)
{
id myArrayElement  = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"%@", myArrayElement.number);
}

for(i = 0; i<2; ++i)
{
NSLog(@"%@", myArray[i].number);    
}
```

Now here two array value you are extracting 
[myArray objectAtIndex:i] which is equivalent to myArray[i]

Comment: This is not an answer and is already addressed in the comments.

Comment: @jason,Forgot to put number method after array, anyways answer is already given so i am late but anyways thanks for notifying me:) also have modified code

Comment: ah, that makes all the difference :)